# How to move Google Sheets rows while preserving the conditional formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have situation where i need to move the entire row when the status changed to "**All Picked**" as shown in COL `A3` , here i would like to mention i have array forumula in COL `A3` which calculate the status together with condtional formatting.

So far i have found below code which can help me move the entire row to the bottom of the sheet only when i manually enter in  "All Picked" in COL `A` , but in real COL `A` is calculating the Status automatically by a  array formula which is :

```
=arrayformula(if(B3:B="",,if(E3:E = 0,"All Picked",if((E3:E <> 0) * (D3:D < C3:C) * not((D3:D = 0) + (D3:D = "")),"partial qty picked",if((E3:E <> 0) * ((D3:D = 0) + (D3:D = "")),"Not yet picked","")))))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a row moved to the bottom once the Status A column value is changed to " All Picked" keeping the formula intact. I dont want to manually insert the status.

Sheet name is: Sheet1, Colume in which status displaying is COL `A`
The trigger is need when the status changed to " All Picked"

Here is code which i found on stackoverflow , i dont  need the condition of HOLD , but since i have no knowledge of it i dont know how to change it.

```
        function onEdit(e) {
          const row = e.range.getRow();
          const col = e.range.getColumn();
          const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
          const lc = as.getLastColumn();
          if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 1  && row > 1 && as.getRange(row,col).getValue() == 'All Picked') {
            const row_new = as.getRange(row, 1, 1, lc);
            row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lc));
            as.deleteRow(row);
          } else if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 2  && row > 1 && as.getRange(row,col).getValue() == 'HOLD'){
            as.insertRowAfter(1);
            const row_new = as.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, lc);
            row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(2, 1, 1, lc));
            as.deleteRow(row + 1);
          }
       }
```

Here is the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMjOXm0uAXsmEEs_nUEgHHFRGwbMG_4P5TDgYCxwyvw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: '*when the status changed to "All Picked"*' It depends HOW exactly the status could be changed. If it's changing by some function I have bad news for you. Sheet functions can not fire scripts. You need to change something on the sheet manually and then you can use `onEdit()` function that will check and change any cells you want.

Comment: @YuriKhristich yes status change on based on formula , so the other solution i think of is to focus on Col D as it will be manually enter column always ,to have the script run whenever C or D are edited (depends on my workflow, but I think D), check column E, and move the row if the adjacent E is 0.

#google-apps-script

Comment: *i think of is to focus on Col D as it will be manually enter column always ,to have the script run whenever C or D are edited...* yes, looks like it should work fine. Do you need a guidance?

Comment: @YuriKhristich yes mate , i know Zero coding , i am very new to googhe sheets as well. i dont know how to modify that code to meet my requirements. Thus need help from the experts like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which will move current row to the bottom of the table whenever you change cells in columns `C` or `D` and a cell in column `A` contains 'All Picked' is here:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // get sheet where edit was happen
  var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (as.getName() != "Sheet1") return; 

  // get current row
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if (row == 1) return; // stop it's first row
 
  // get column
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (col != 3 && col != 4 ) return; // stop if it's not 3 and not 4 column

  // get a first cell or the row
  var value = as.getRange("A"+row).getDisplayValue();
  if (value != 'All Picked') return; // stop if it doesn't contain 'All Picked'
  
  // move current row to the bottom of the table
  var lc = as.getLastColumn();
  var row_new = as.getRange(row, 1, 1, lc);
  row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lc));
  as.deleteRow(row);
 
}
```

But I don't understand your formula. I'm not sure what it does. The code will copy the formula as is (if it is in the cell, which is not the case for the most of rows in your table).

If you need that the row indexes in a formula weren't changing during copy, probably you need to use absolute references `B$3:B` instead of `B3:B` etc.

https://www.goskills.com/Excel/Resources/Absolute-reference-Excel

Comment: Wow , your code is working fine , but i still running into problems. 

P.S since my comments is too long i have pasted here
https://jpst.it/2xPKl

Comment: Okay. But I still confused your formula. As far as I can understand the logic, the formula should be like this: `=arrayformula(if(B3="",,if(E3 = 0,"All Picked",if((E3 <> 0) * (D3 < C3) * not((D3 = 0) + (D3 = "")),"partial qty picked",if((E3 <> 0) * ((D3 = 0) + (D3 = "")),"Not yet picked","")))))` I just pasted this formula in column A of your sheet. Look if it works correctly.

Comment: Awesome , its working like charm , you are my hero , thank you man.

Comment: @ Yuri Khristich
its not working for my editors , only working for me "Owner" as i have some ranges as protected where some editors are not allowed to edit , is there any fix for it ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know. Probably you need full access to the sheet to do it (to move rows) indeed. I can be wrong, though.